# How to get last child in intersection observer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, intersection-observer

I have a webpage in which this section will be added. I want to apply position fixed when the first section comes in middle and scroll starts and when the last section come in middle the position of .BG changes to relative so it cannot affect the other divs of the web page.

Is there a way to observe last child and apply position relative to BG

```js
const bgEl = document.querySelector(".BG");
const bgEl2 = document.querySelector(".section");

function createObserver(el) {
  let observer;
  let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
  };

  function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        const url = entry.target.getAttribute("BGurl");
        bgEl.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
        bgEl.style.position = "fixed";
      } else {
        bgEl.style.position = "relative";
      }
    });
  }

  observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
  observer.observe(el);
  return observer;
}

(function() {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".main .section");
  const observers = Array.from(sections).map(function(section) {
    createObserver(section);
  });
})();
```

```css
.main {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100% 100% !important;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
}

.text p {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 149%;
  color: #263244;
}

.text h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.text .story-detail {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(76.31% 191.89% at 13.43% 22.19%, rgba(226, 228, 231, 0.8) 0%, rgba(228, 228, 229, 0.368) 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  padding: 23px;
}

.text .story-description {
  width: 321px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(76.31% 191.89% at 13.43% 22.19%, rgba(226, 228, 231, 0.8) 0%, rgba(228, 228, 229, 0.368) 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  padding: 23px;
}

.BG {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="BG"></div>
  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/9QYL3ytR/mobile-camp.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <h1>Our Story</h1>
        <div class="story-detail">
          <p>
            We saw a gap between what people need and what banks offer. It means millions of us aren't getting the banking experience we deserve for different reasons.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/9QYL3ytR/mobile-camp.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <div class="story-description">
          <p>
            Traditional banks don’t focus on customers' experience, their systems may be slow and outdated, they may prioritize a specific group of people, or perhaps they lack the ability to innovate, and so on.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/cLPLS8xW/mobile-desert.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <div class="story-description">
          <p>
            So since we're passionate about solving problems and bridging gaps, we looked into and identified the challenges and capabilities we'll need to build a bank here in the Kingdom.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/mZnqV38T/mobile-birds.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <div class="story-description">
          <p>
            With the best local and international expertise, we began building an innovative digital bank designed by and for the people. We believe that the most effective way to build a bank for people is to do it with them. This is our philosophy. So, we started
            building it with the help of people like you.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.postimg.cc/k513m0Fb/mountain.png">
    <div class="text">
      <div style="margin-inline: 20px">
        <div class="story-description">
          <p>
            At D360, innovation starts with someone’s passion for improving financial services. To that person, we say: Never stop offering solutions to your needs. These solutions will not only benefit you, but will significantly impact the lives of millions.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```